# How do I get the hex color from an RGB color?

Tags: go, colors

I am reading an image and getting its colors in RGB via `image/color`. However, I want to convert a [color](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Color) to [hex triplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet). How do I do this?

```
img, err := jpeg.Decode(someImg)
color := img.At(x, y) # I would like to convert this from RGB to hex
```

Answer (score 4):

Hex is just hexadecimal representation of RGB values you can simply do something like

```
fmt.Printf("#%02x%02x%02x", R, G, B)
```

Play Link: https://play.golang.org/p/bU510RaYle8